# Robot Framework dialog pop-up issue

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using the `Get value from user` command in the Robot Framework with the *Selenium2Library* to get an input from the user.

Then, when the pop-up for entering the message appears, it appears in the back end of the browser and the user may not be aware that any pop-up has come up:

```
Get value from user    Enter CAPCHA to proceed !!    none    none
```

How can I make the pop-up dialog to appear above the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can possibly control this but, perhaps you could try setting your window's size and position so that you can see the dialog?

Check out the keywords `Set Window Size` and `Set Window Position`